# MySQL: How Online DDL INPLACE Algorithm with data copy works?

Tags: mysql

I read the document about online ddl in mysql 5.7
(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html)

This document explains that even in case of using ALGORITHM=INPLACE, data copy can still happen;

" ... When an operation on the primary key uses ALGORITHM=INPLACE, even though the data is still copied, it is more efficient than using ALGORITHM=COPY because ..."

I can't understand this clearly. Does 'data is still copied' mean that the operation use temporary tables? or some other temporary space like online buffer?

Comment: Way to broad to answer..

Comment: But how i geuss it works is when `ALGORITHM=COPY` is used then a external file is used to copy to, When `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` is used it extends the current table file and copies the data internally in that file and marks the old data as "deleted" to be new locations for new records (also one off the reasons you should not be trusting to fetch data on insert order) .. Most likely the buffer_pool will also be involved in both to speed up the write on disk